# How to add an argument to a function in python Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm really sorry about the title being so unclear. Here is my issue. Say I have a code like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(str):
    print(str)
    root.destroy()

btn = Button(root,text='destroy',command=callback('Hello world!'))

btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However, when I executed this an error popped out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abc/Documents/test/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    btn = Button(root,text='destroy',command=callback('Hello world!'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2647, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2569, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

I figured out that I can't write `command=callback()` with the parentheses, instead I should write `command=callback` in order to make the program function correctly. However, it seemed that it only worked when no argument is required. If I need to pass an argument, the argument(s) **should** be in a pair of parentheses [e.g."*callback('hello world!')*"]. How can I pass an argument without writing a pair of parentheses? Thanks.

Comment: Change `command=callback('Hello world!')` into `command=lambda:callback('Hello world!')`

Answer (score 2):

as TheLizzard has pointed out, change `command = callback('Hello world!')` into `command = lambda: callback('Hello world!')`, since just putting without lambda calls the function, but if you put it in a lambda it becomes like a mini function since lambdas are callable, the argument for `command` if I remember correctly, The given argument should callable, like a function for example